# How to add SSL cert to awscli / aws sdk for AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-cli

I am writing a program that utilizes the AWS Price API. I use the AWS SDK and have been getting away with not using an SSL with using the `--no-verify-ssl` tag at the end of the commands.

However I'd like to add an SSL cert so I am able to run these without an error. How would I add an SSL cert so that I am able to communicate with the AWS Price API?

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: I think you might look into how to import an SSL certificate into the windows trusted store.

Comment: Solved this. It was an issue with my company's local ca cert that needed to be identified when making CLI commands. I downloaded it and created a variable in my ```config``` file.

```ca_bundle = C:\Path\to\Root.crt```